# Android How to Create a Background System Service like APP to be a Bridge Between User Apps and Hardware/Hardware Drivers

Tags: android

For an android development board, I will customize the open source Android operating system offered by the manufacturer according to my needs.

To put it briefly, i will develop

-Drivers for my hardware modules. (like card reader) For some devices i'll use third party drivers which i do not have the source codes.

-A background system service like app. (Which will allow applications to communicate with hardware, like a bridge) (For example if an user app want to communicate with my card reader it should use this service.)

What i want to do is my hardware modules (like card reader, fingerprint sensor and etc.) should be only visible to my background system service. Other user applications should not access devices or device drivers directly.

My background system service will always run on background and wait for requests from user applications. It should handle lots of requests at the same time.

My question are :

1. How can i make device drivers and devices (like usb card reader) only visible/available to my system service?
2. How should I impelement such a background service? Can you summarize very briefly?
3. Is there a logical error or something against the basics of the Android operating system in what I want to do?